# Problemas al solicitar detalles de una suscripción paypal

Tags: php, json, curl, get, paypal

Resulta que estoy intentando hacer una solicitud http GET para obtener los detalles de una subscripción de Paypal para comprobar si existe. Ejemplo de la documentación oficial: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G \
-H 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-CONTEXT: {"consumer":{"accountNumber":1181198218909172527,"merchantId":"5KW8F2FXKX5HA"},"merchant":{"accountNumber":1659371090107732880,"merchantId":"2J6QB8YJQSJRJ"},"apiCaller":{"clientId":"AdtlNBDhgmQWi2xk6edqJVKklPFyDWxtyKuXuyVT-OgdnnKpAVsbKHgvqHHP","appId":"APP-6DV794347V142302B","payerId":"2J6QB8YJQSJRJ","accountNumber":"1659371090107732880"},"scopes":["https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/subscription/.*","https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscription","openid"]}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Lo que no entniendo es porque dentro del diccionario "consumer" me pide un "merchantID" y un accountNumber si el cliente no tiene por qué ser vendedor. Quizás lo esté interprentando mal, en ese caso me gustaría saber que son esos valores.

Y gracias de antemano.

Comment: La documentación no menciona que sea necesario. ¿qué te devuelve el API si omites el dato?

Comment: Lo de siempre: {"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error","rel":"information_link"}]}. Aunque se me pasó mencionar que al no ver "appid" ni "accountNumber" (que por cierto según he leido no existe número de cuenta) no los incluí en la petición

Comment: La documentación indica que hay que enviar headers de autenticación. Ya sea el bearer token o usuario_id y _secret_. Esos datos si o si deben ir en el request.

Comment: Ahora probaré es que no los ví en el código de ejemplo de la documetación el bearer y el ID secreto. Tan solo vi que estaba el ID cliente.

Comment: No están en el código de ejemplo, pero si que los menciona. Mi primera sospecha es que ese código de ejemplo podría ser incorrecto.